# Reduce latency of long distance VPN location

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

I am connected to a clients network via ovpn. Their servers are located in Germany whilst I am currently in Indonesia which results into a very high ping of ~350ms. I found one workaround by using an Azure VM located in the US and connecting to ovpn within the Windows VM. I will get a ping of around 150 ms. Since my network is generally slow (around 30 Mbps). I am trying to find another solution to get the lowest latency possible

Comment: You got 150 ms by using high-speed connections to-from the USA. This is already pretty good. You may shave off some milliseconds by finding faster-connected VPN networks/servers.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at online rtt tables, between Jakarta and Frankfurt you're looking at 160/170ms. Even if you look at it theoretically; Jakarta->Frankfurt is ~11.000km in a straight line, and taking into account the refractive index of fiber media, you're looking at 53ms latency just in light travel time (one way), times two for a roundtrip is 106ms. Unless you plan to dig a fiber through the planet, you're not getting around that 100ms.

The only meaningful way to reduce the latency you're facing, without violating the laws of physics is, is to reduce the number of hops between you and the client. Every hop will introduce *some* latency. Ideally you'd set up your own backbone, with photonic switches, but assuming you don't have 100-200 million to set that up, it's probably best to look at commercial VPN solutions.

A commercial VPN can reduce the number of hops between you and Germany, because they control their own traffic flow (which you can't, because your ISP controls it). If you go with a big provider (CloudFlare VPN?) they are also likely to have less hops, because they would have their own backbone, and not rely on other ISPs to route their traffic, but it's probably best to try a few. I can imagine not every VPN provider would optimize for the Indonesia<->Germany path, but you might get lucky with one.

The rest is down to mitigating the impact of the latency. For example, for SSH special clients exist that do local echo and all that. Maybe you can look into latency-optimized clients for your application.

Comment: If I am connected to a VM located in Germany is that speedwise similar to being connected to a VPN Server based in Germany?

Comment: What do you mean? You really have to be much more specific in your question. "located to a VM" doesn't make any sense (grammar and semantics).

Comment: Sorry I meant "connected to a VM". I edited my comment straight away but you were too quick to respond.

Comment: It depends on how you connect to that VM. If the connection to the VM takes the same path as the regular connection, it'd have similar latency. Being "connected to a VPN server based in Germany" is ambiguous. Is it the connection TO the VPN server from you or FROM the VPN server to the target system? Try to understand the part of my post about the routing and the hops. A VPN in itself won't reduce your latency. The alternative backhaul that a VPN can provide *might* reduce your latency (by routing you over a more optimal path).